# Android fullscreen app - prevent access to status bar

Tags: android, android-service, fullscreen, android-statusbar

I am creating a fullscreen app which will run in "kiosk" mode, so the user will not be able to exit. The app is defined as a launcher (home screen).

The `Activity` in the manifest is defined with:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Additionally, the `Activity` ensures full screen mode with the following in its `onCreate()`:

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

However, it seems that the status bar is still accessible. It's hidden by default, but it can still be shown by touching and pulling down the top of the screen (where it shows with a translucent background instead of the usual solid black).

I already know I can prevent this by adding a transparent 10`px` system overlay window at the top of the screen which will absorb the touch events. But I removed this hack because I didn't think it was necessary.

I am sure this was all working fine and prevented the status bar from showing without resorting to the hackery. But something has changed somewhere. I have updated to the latest stock firmware and system software - perhaps that has changed this?

The device is currently running `Android` 4.4.4. I believe it may have been on 4.4.1 before.

Has this ever been possible? Is it more likely that something has changed in `Android` or I have broken something, or has this been broken all along and I've only just noticed?

Please note that this is for a specialised industrial device (a Honeywell Dolphin 75e) which cannot be rooted.

Comment: hello i am working on the same type of application can you please help. I am try to disable status bar and home and history btn

Comment: I ended up having to stick with a transparent overlay in my app that intercepts the touch events.

Comment: Can you please share a code with me because I tried that but the the navigation show above the stick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it seems that the status bar is still accessible.

Yes, because the `com.android.systemui` package is running which is responsible for the status bar and software navigation bar. The following is a couple of solutions on disabling the package. ***Note*** *that in order to make use of the solutions the extended privileges (ideally `root`) are needed*.

### Reboot persistent solution

Rename the `apk` extension of `/system/app/SystemUI.apk` or delete the file completely. You have to remount the `/system` partition as it is read-only by default. After renaming/deleting the system likely uninstall the `/data/data/com.android.systemui` package. If not, do it manually, then reboot.

### Reboot impermanent solution

Disable/enable the framework service at runtime (e.g. on your app start up) with the calls (valid **prior to `KitKat`** at least) to:

```
service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui  // disable status bar
```

and

```
am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService  // enable status bar
```

Note, the solution is not persistent on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in oncreate method

```
int myflag= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(myflag);
```

for more details
https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to make any difference, the status bar still becomes visible when pulled down from the top. From the immersive page: "The user can reveal the system bars with an inward swipe along the region where the system bars normally appear".