# Hide navigation and status bar

Tags: android

Is it possible to hide the navigation and status bar across all apps in Android. I can do it in my app but I want to change this on an OS level where every app will now be in full screen mode if I hide the soft navigation bar and status bar.

Comment: [Android fullscreen app - prevent access to status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38530475/android-fullscreen-app-prevent-access-to-status-bar)

Comment: I tried that before, does not work, thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The only way you MIGHT be able to do that is to make your app have system level permission. And that is not possible, in most cases.

System level permission requires your app to be signed with system level certificates. To be precise, you need the `platform.x509.pem` and  `platform.pk8` files of the installed OS/ROM.

Unless you created the ROM yourself, you won't have access to those files.

But somehow you do get those files, make a Java KeyStore (`.jks`) file with those files and sign your app with that keystore.