# Hiding the navigation bar immediately on app launch

Tags: android, runtime, launch, android-statusbar, android-navigation-bar

Based on the following code snippets, I was able to hide the status bar **right when the app launches**, but not the navigation bar (the bar consisting of the back, home, and task manager buttons) since it hides **later after MainActivity's thread finishes loading up**:

Here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dpark.sample2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

... here's the styles:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

... and MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

... How do I hide **both** bars from the start **at the same time** like a game or YouTube's full screen mode?

Comment: Any luck on this ?  I have the same requirement.

Comment: Is this really impossible to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Move this line of code to onCreate()-

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

Comment: Tried that already. I even put it before setContentView in onCreate. The delay of the navigation bar being hidden is even more noticeable on devices with a slower RAM such as a 512MB virtual emulator. I just wish <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> hid both bars at the same time to make my life easier...

Answer (score 0):

Im trying to solve this for my splash screen and no luck so far. But you can make things look better if you add this to your style theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

Navigation will be still visible, but translucent. This is how my theme looks like now:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ps_splash_screen</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onCreate

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```