# Is it possible to prevent the status bar on first touch for Android API Level < 19?

Tags: android, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

The following is [the official way](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) of hiding the status bar:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

However, the status bar shows up on the first touch.  Is it possible to prevent this.  One can use getWindow().getDecorView().setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() to hide it again, but its brief display is a nuisance. 
For API 19 and above, [Immersive Full-Screen Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) is available for dealing with this.

Comment: Could [Android fullscreen app - prevent access to status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38530475/3290339) help?

Comment: Thank you for the pointer.  I was looking for a solution that will work for an activity.

Comment: the accepted answer mentions a solution for hiding the status bar at run-time by calling `service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui`. You might try to pass the string in `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` on Activity start.

Comment: I need a solution for API level as low as 16.  That method appears to be available for API 19 and above according to the answer.

Comment: The solution works for older versions. Maybe my English wasn't good enough when answering :) I should edit it

Comment: The answer says "valid as of KitKat", so I thought it required API 19 or above.