# Disable Statusbar and Navigationbar

Tags: java, android, statusbar

my question is about enable/disable status bar and navigation bar in android,not just hiding it , but exactly disable it .

i used

```
setSystemUiVisibility()
```

Function and its implementation just can hide status bar and navigation bar .

Is there anyway to disable/enable Statusbar and navigation bar ?

i searched a alot but not found anything usefull .

any suggestion is usefull , thanks .

here is the code that i tried :

```
 @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
```

and this is just hide the statusbar and navigation bar ,  and not disable status bar and navigation 
bar .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38530475/3290339

Comment: Add this line of code above the `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` . Above the `setContentView`

Comment: execuse me , i tried this with android 4.2.2 and it worked , but when i tested it on android 7.1 this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this line of the code for it above the **`setContentView()`**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT)



}
```

Comment: This is Only Works For Android 4.2.2 and Not Work for Android 7

Comment: It should be workable for those also...I have tried the same lines of code for Oreo and lower devices..And it's working perfectly...

Comment: hi can you plz tell me where is this Layout coming from I am using react native  setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT)

Comment: @BilalYaqoob ..Sorry i can not help you in React-native..It is for native android..

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha I am writing native android using java react native also have android java code